# Azure App Service removes origin with custom scheme after adding to Azure Exlorer

Tags: azure, cors, azure-web-app-service

I was asked to add this origin to the CORS setting of App Service in Azure

```
capacitor://localhost
```

I successfully added the origin to the App Service's CORS using Azure Explorer

However, after a couple of minutes, the origin I just added in Azure Explorer is suddenly removed

Is there a reason why this happens?

The other origin with https are the origins remained in the CORS setting

Comment: CORS is an HTTP header based mechanism to allow other domains make request to your current domain/scheme/port.

Comment: yes but the the API deployed in App services are going to be consumed by iOS app which has the custom scheme

I just don't get why that origin is getting removed after I added it in Azure Explorer that was suggested from the search

Answer (score 0):

App Service CORS example. It is not allowed to add the schema you are adding:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is understood, so I used the Azure Explorer to add origin with custom scheme to the CORS setting. But for some reason, its getting removed after a couple of minutes. I just dont get why its happening

Comment: This is related to your client. Check this out: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/basics/configuring-your-app#common-configuration